# Two submit buttons in a JSP without multiple forms, same controller

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I have read the similar topics [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025280/have-multiple-submit-buttons-in-a-form-and-determine-which-was-pressed-in-a-cont), and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938302/processing-multiple-submit-buttons-in-jsp) but it did not help with my problem.

I created a simple JavaEE mvc web app. The jsp page contains a form with two text fields and two buttons. The first text field to enter an Id, the second to enter a name. Depending on which button is clicked a Servlet routes to the appropriate method (Search by ID or Search by Name).
Search by id method works correctly. And I see the following path in the address bar: `http://localhost:8080/employees_war_exploded/ControllerServlet?textEmployeeId=1&command=Search_ID&employeeName=`

However there is a problem with a Search by name method. It does not show any results. Here is what I see in the address bar: `http://localhost:8080/employees_war_exploded/ControllerServlet?textEmployeeId=&employeeName=ann&command=Search_Name`

I guess the problem is that in both cases it gets the parameters of both text fields ("textEmployeeId" and "employeeName"). How can I make it process both inputs separately in the same form? Maybe there is some other reason for the problem that I do not see?

```html
<form class="form-style" name="form1">
  <label>ID:
    <input type="text" name="textEmployeeId" value="${tempEmployee.id}" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="command" value="Search_ID">
  <br>
  <br>

  <label>Name:
    <input type="text" name="employeeName" value="${tempEmployee.name}" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="command" value="Search_Name">
  <br>
  <br>
</form>
```

**ControllerServlet.java**

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String theCommand = request.getParameter("command");

            if (theCommand == null) {
                theCommand = "EMPLOYEE_LIST";
            }

            // route to the appropriate method
            switch (theCommand) {
                case "EMPLOYEE_LIST":
                    listEmployees(request, response);
                    break;   
                case "Search_ID":
                    searchById(request, response);
                    break;
                case "Search_Name":
                    searchByName(request, response);
                    break;
                default:
                    listEmployees(request, response);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
private void searchByName(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String nameString = request.getParameter("employeeName");

        List<Employee> namedEmployees = employeeDbUtil.searchEmployees(nameString);
        request.setAttribute("EMPLOYEES", namedEmployees);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/search-by-name.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);


    }


 private void searchById(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

            String textString = request.getParameter("textEmployeeId");

             Employee theEmployee = employeeDbUtil.getEmployeeById(textString);
                request.setAttribute("THE_EMPLOYEE", theEmployee);

                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/show-employee.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }

        }
```

Update: I'm getting a NullPointerException for the searchByName method. Could there be a problem with this method from a DAO class that is called from ControllerServlet?

```
public List<Employee> searchEmployees(String employeeName) throws Exception {
    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList();

    Connection myConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        employeeName += "%";
        preparedStatement = myConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE LOWER(name) like LOWER(?)");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, employeeName);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Employee tempEmployee = resultSetToEmployee(resultSet);
            employeeList.add(tempEmployee);
        }
        return employeeList;
    }
    finally {
        DbExceptions.close(resultSet);
        DbExceptions.close(preparedStatement);
        DbExceptions.close(myConnection);
    }

}
```

Comment: why not use two forms as a matter of interest?

Comment: It could be there just aren't any results, is it redirecting you to `search-by-name.jsp`? It looks like your servlet execution flow goes off of the command attribute and just accesses other attributes based on the command.

Comment: @David I read that using multiple forms in the same jsp is not a good practice. And I'm also curious if there is a way to solve it without multiple forms.

Comment: @zack6849 When I press Search_ID everything executes correctly. And I'm redirected to the `/show-employee.jsp` page showing the expected result. But when I press Search_Name button I'm getting a NullPointerException. And it's not redirecting me to the `search-by-name.jsp` page. There's just a blank white browser page.

Comment: check to make sure the employees list is actually not empty, your code looks like it should run fine

Comment: @zack6849 It appears to be empty. But I can not figure out how to fix this. Updated the post with the implementation of a DAO method that's called from the servlet.

Comment: check your request parameter isn't null or default the string to be empty if it is String nameString = request.getParameter("employeeName") == null ? "" : request.getParameter("employeeName");

Comment: @David Thank you for your help. I found the solution.. there was a problem with the `searchEmployees(String employeeName)` method from DAO class. As you can see there is a line `Connection myConnection = null;` but I'm not getting the connection from a DataSource. So the method returned an empty list. Adding the following line `myConnection = dataSource.getConnection();` into the "try" block solved the problem.